# Samsung Galaxy s3 4.3 update failing

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, updates, 4.3-jelly-bean

I am trying to update the firmware of my **Galaxy S3 from 4.1.2 to 4.3**. The update package gets downloded, **but the installation fails at 31% everytime**. I tried to updated using **KIES** also, but no success. What can be the reason and how can I resolve this issue?

The Error message is "**Failed to update the firmware. Try again with Kies or contact Samsung**".

Comment: Today I found out that my samsung account was not updated. Can that be can issue?

Comment: Try updating the samsung account I guess. My S4 updated fine without updating it though. If that fails, is there any error message or anything showing at all? Can you download the firmware from sammobile and manually flash it?

Comment: The error messgae is just "Installation of the package failed , try using Kies or contact samsung". No I havent tried that. I will give it a try.

Comment: Currently the update is not availaible on sammobile for my location.

Comment: You haven't rooted have you? Do you have a custom recovery installed? Is you device status 'custom' at all?

Comment: No I havent rooted it.My device status is Normal.

Comment: Wait til it is up on SamMobile (usually fast and you can contact them if it isnt' there), then flash it yourself seems to be the best option. Is the whole OTA.zip donwloading correctly? It may be showing as complete, but it suggests something is wrong. Try updating everything else in the meantime and see if it helps. Contact your network provider about this also if needs be.

Comment: I have a guess: Problematic update package was released for your region, like  it was in UK, and your phone started download, than they removed the update from servers after so many complaints about the issues it have. So, what I am trying to say is; 31% is the part you have already and since it is not accesible from the samsung servers, you can not download the remaining.

Comment: The download is not the problem. Its completing the full download of 400Mb something.. then the installation process is started and it fails at 31%. I dont think there is a problem in update package, because other people just updated there firmfare in s3 in my region.

Comment: While this is a nuclear option, a factory reset may solve the update issue for you. Of course, you'll lose the data on your phone.

Comment: I have this option too in my mind, a last one though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those of you who had tried OTA (over the air) or used KIES to update - and failed. My recommendation is FLASH your smartphone using software. I went to an authorised Samsung dealer who flashed my phone - and didn't have to backup either - and it took only 10 - 15 minutes, in total. Flashing uses proprietary software.

Comment: I will install the update manually using ODIN.If it works then well and good.

Comment: I have a Samsung Galaxy S3 which had firmware 4.1.1. After patiently waiting since October last year for 4.3JB update,  I became impatient, after Sammobile kept saying that 'Uk...Pending'. So I went last week to an authorised Samsung Dealer.  He flashed my phone and the whole operation took approx 12mins. Now I am a 'happy bunny' and my phone works perfectly fine. No problems.

Comment: I updated my phone today by flashing my ROM using ODIN and it worked. Although I didn't go to a Samsung Dealer, but still I am going to accept your answer as it made me more confident in flashing my ROM. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Not all models of galaxy s3 support update to 4.3 jelly bean at this moment. This update is model, carrier & location specific. You can google about it.

Having update through `OTA` is the best choice as you always shall receive legal update `(stock firmware)` through it. If `OTA` fails to receive the update you should understand that either your device model or carrier isn't supporting the update legally.

However, `Samsung Kies` also plays role as legal update booster which you are unable to receive through `OTA`. If you are unable to receive the update via `Samsung Kies` you can be sure that there is no legal update of stock firmware available for your device.

If you are still eager to update your device to 4.3.2 jelly bean, flashing the `ROM` is the onliest choice. You can download the `custom firmware` of android 4.3.2 jelly bean either

from

http://live.samsung-updates.com/
or

http://sammobile.com

which isn't `location+carrier` specific (download only location specific firmware) and flash it through `ODIN. You shall do that at your own risk. You of course shall backup your device before you do that as you may encounter some incompatibility issues after you flash the custom firmware.

For most of the android versions, you must have your device rooted in order to flash custom firmware. There are many operating system specific resources available on the net about how to root your device.

You can learn more about `ClockworkMod (CWM)` recovery & `TeamWin Recovery Project (TWRP)` before you root your device.

Anyway, don't forget to install the root keeping app like `Root Keeper` and super user app like `SuperSu` after you root your device in order to manage your `rooted android` as well as keep `OTA` alive.